# Increase the value related to an index for each time the index is present

Tags: r

I need to create a sparse 3d tensor, currently using package tensorr. As an input we need

```
sptensor(idx, vals, dims)
```

*idx* is (x,y,z) , the tensor-index for the corresponding value in *vals*. *dims* is the total dimensions of the tensor.

In my list of *idx* I have duplicated indexes. What I need then is for the value in *vals* to increase with each occurence. So for each value in the *idx* list, *vals* is 1, but when an entry in *idx* is a duplicate of a previously counted entry then the vals should increase linearly (so *vals* is 2 if 2 occurences of same index, 3 if it happens 3 times etc).

A simple reproducible sample:

```
idx <- list(c(1,1,2),c(2,2,2),c(1,1,2), c(1,2,1),c(1,1,2))
vals <- integer(5)+1
dims <- c(2,2,2)
sptensor(idx,vals,dims)

<A 2x2x2 sparse tensor with 3 non-zero entries>
subs: <1,2,1> <1,1,2> <2,2,2>
vals: 1 1 1
```

but here I would need the *vals* output to be vals: 1 3 1 since the index occured 3 times.

At first I thought about using duplicated, so vals is initiated as all zeros. Then, at index !duplicated(idx), we add +1. Then at index duplicated(idx) we add another +1. But this strategy crashes when we have more than 2 occurences of the same index.

Anyone got a good idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I ended up solving it: [Best way to store multidim index and corresponding value in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46218970/best-way-to-store-multidim-index-and-corresponding-value-in-r)