# Best way to store multidim index and corresponding value in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list of indexes in 3 dimensions;

```
> head(TW_idx, n = 4)
[[1]]
[1]   1   1 135

[[2]]
[1]  1  2 96

[[3]]
[1]   1   3 120

[[4]]
[1]   1   1 135
```

Each index corresponds to a value of 100. However, one index can occur more than one times in *TW_idx* (here in list 1 and 4) and for each occurence of the index, the value increases linearly (so if one index is present 3 times, the value of that index is 300). I want to find a way to store the index with its corresponding value.

My thought is that we create a dataframe which would look smth like

```
> df
 idx    value
1,1,135  200
1,2,96   100
1,3,120  100
```

for the 4 values above but I am not sure how to create it. Even better would be if I could get an output where the indexes are just the same list without duplicates (i.e. TW_idx <- unique(TW_idx) ) and the values are stored in a list/numeric list of the same length where each element describes the value for the corresponding element in the new (without duplicates) TW_idx list. But if it is simpler to get the dataframe, I would be very happy with that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If there are consistently 3 indices, consider storing them in 3 separate variables. This will be much easier to work with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this enough? Basically I create a character variable from each list element. It is assumed that they are consistently written down. It is trivial to count the number of times each combination occurs. Right now the result is in raw count but there's really nothing stopping you to multiply this by 100.

```
x <- list(c(1, 1, 135),
         c(1, 2, 96),
         c(1, 3, 120),
         c(1, 1, 135))

out <- as.data.frame(table(sapply(x, FUN = paste, collapse = ",")))
out

     Var1 Freq
1 1,1,135    2
2  1,2,96    1
3 1,3,120    1
```

If you need the data in a list form, you can split it row-wise.

```
split(out, 1:nrow(out))

$`1`
     Var1 Freq
1 1,1,135    2

$`2`
    Var1 Freq
2 1,2,96    1

$`3`
     Var1 Freq
3 1,3,120    1
```

Comment: I need to use the index as a numeric list later, so the entries in Var1 should preferably still be numeric rather than character

Comment: But it looks like a good solution, I will try to use it and see if it works

Comment: Oh yes it started working now, what I did was use out$Var1 <-
 lapply(out$Var1, as.character) and then I used newidxlist <- lapply(out$Var1, f) where 

f <- function(x){
  as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(unlist(x), ",")))
}

and I have two lists of same length, one with indexes (each list element is a numeric list) and one with their corresponding values. Thanks Roman, marked as solved!